# mutually independent events

Tags: probability

In my it is given as below [image]

Can anybody explain how they have written for n events.

Answer (score 0):

We want to count how many conditions we can construct of the following form where $\rm S$ is a subset of $\{A_1,..,A_n\}$ that contains two or more elements.$$\mathsf P(\bigcap\limits_{A_k\in\mathrm S} A_k)=\prod\limits_{A_k\in\mathrm S}\mathsf P(A_k)$$

In other words we simply want to count how many distinct subsets of $\{A_1,..,A_n\}$ contain *at least* two elements.

We can count this by the series, $\newcommand{\ch}[2]{{^{#1}{\!\mathrm C}_{#2}}}\sum\limits_{j=2}^n\ch nj$, since $\ch n j$ counts distinct ways to select a set of $j$ elements from a set of size $n$.

$$\sum\limits_{j=2}^n \ch nj ~=~ \ch n 2+\ch n 3+\ldots+\ch n{n-1}+\ch nn$$

However, it is simpler to notice that $2^n$ counts the number of subsets of a set of size $n$ (that is, it is the size of the power set), then we must exclude the count of those with only one element, and also the empty set.

$$\sum\limits_{j=2}^n\ch nj~=~2^n-n-1$$

---

PS: This is basically an application of the Binomial Theorem.